# Syntax with iPad

Tags: support, markdown, mobile-web

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Is there a way to enter back tick (backtick) on SO when using iPad or iPhone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133673/is-there-a-way-to-enter-back-tick-backtick-on-so-when-using-ipad-or-iphone)

Might be a duplicate, but I haven't found a question covering this very issue: When using SO on iPad (and likely iPhone), I'm facing the issue that I can't type backticks for inline monospaced font. I read somewhere that this'll get fixed in iOS 4.2, but in the meantime, is there an alternative to using backticks or some trick in iOS that I'm unaware of ?