# Is there a way to enter back tick (backtick) on SO when using iPad or iPhone?

Tags: support, ipad, backtick

There are times when I only can use iPad to access SO, and the back tick ` is needed to quote the literals...  but it seems on iPad, there is no way to enter a back tick on the keyboard?  Can it be somehow entered?

Comment: I never owned an iPad. Do you browse the mobile or the normal version of the site?

Comment: @Dennis iPad defaults to the normal version of the site.

Comment: Not a fully fledged answer as I don't own one of these things, but there are probably many useful keyboard tweaks on Cydia. At a glance, [BTstack Keyboard](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/ch.ringwald.keyboard) and [iKeywi](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/org.thebigboss.ikeywi) look to be very useful.

Comment: BTW most of these workarounds also work on my Surface, whose onscreen keyboard does not include the backtick. The {} button is probably the most useful. I'm adding this comment to help those who might search for `Surface` and `backtick`

Comment: @JamesHaigh, Without jailbreaking possible?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Assuming you're using the US keyboard layout, tap the <kbd>.?123</kbd> key, then tap and hold the <kbd>'</kbd> key: a popup will appear where you can tap the <kbd>`</kbd> key. If I remember correctly, this only works in iOS 4 and later: if you're still running iPhone OS 3.2, you're out of luck and you really should just upgrade already.

Comment: wow, this is such a hidden feature

Comment: @動靜能量 to be fair, outside of SE, how many times do you use backticks in everyday text?

Comment: I don't use any other websites beside SE... haha... almost

Comment: I use it when writing documentation for my code on my iPad.

Comment: @user149432, Typing passwords

Comment: Slack uses them as well.

Comment: Thanks for this! It works for the UK keyboard as well.

Comment: Use it with slack on my iPhone

Comment: Thanks!  Really helped me.  I use it to edit Github markdown pages with code block pasted in. Using iPad Pro.

Answer (score 9):

@MarkTrapp said that iPad defaults to the non-mobile version of Stack Overflow, so you don't really *need* to press the <kbd>`</kbd>.

Just click the `Code Sample` icon over the textarea, and it will insert two backticks. If you select the literals first, it will automatically wrap them in backticks.

Note that the `Code Sample` button insert four spaces rather than backticks if triggered on an empty or entire line.

Comment: oh good quick way.  seems like you have to type something first, and then click the "Code" icon button...  if nothing is typed beforehand on the line, then it will indent by 4 spaces

Comment: Right, I forgot about that part.

Comment: This also only works for regular posts. You can't use the buttons on comments...

Answer (score 6):

You can surround the text you want to inline monospace with `<code></code>`.

This works for questions and answers, but not for comments -- right now, I don't think there's a workaround for comments.

Comment: Good to know that this works for answers, that might be enough... At least it's better than nothing :-)

Answer (score 3):

### Comments

In a comment box, click help at the bottom right, select and copy the `` `code` `` from there and paste it, replacing the word *code* with your actual code.

### Answers

Similarly, in an answer box, you can click the ? at the top right and under Code, you can select and copy `$` and then paste in the textbox, editing `$` out to be your actual code.

`<code>your code here</code>` also works in an answer box.