# Please include how to quote backticks in inline code in Markdown editing help

Tags: feature-request, markdown, editing-help, backtick

I've seen this happen a few times: "`code 'with' backticks` (replace quotes with backticks!!!)"

I also had to do some digging to find out for myself that the correct way to do this: `` code `with` backticks ``

...is this: ``` ``code `with` backticks`` ```

...which I quoted like this: ```` ``` ``code `with` backticks`` ``` ````

...etc.

People often get by by using 4 spaces:

```
code `with` backticks
```

...but of course, this is not possible for mini-Markdown as used in comments, so the comment formatting help should definitely be expanded to explain how to quote backticks inline.

https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Ps. I also notice that leading, trailing and excess whitespace is ignored, so a single preformatted backtick immediately surrounded by parens can be marked-up like this: ``` (`` ` ``) ```

...which renders as: (`` ` ``)

Comment: I think its related to [How to Format sandbox](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3122/165346)?

Comment: Just a tip. I use quotes when on my iPod as there **is no** back tick key

Comment: @Cole: Well I don't know about iOS, but I know for Android there are loads of great alternative keyboards available for download. The most popular for this sort of thing is Hacker's Keyboard, but I also find Flit Keyboard to be very capable (and ergonomic).

Comment: @Cole, are you [sure about that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133673/is-there-a-way-to-enter-back-tick-backtick-on-so-when-using-ipad-or-iphone)?

Comment: For regular Markdown, I think it's nicely covered by [Need More Detail?](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#need-more-detail) in the Markdown help you linked to. Also, [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) has some more detail, also for comments. I guess one can't have all options in the short help.

Comment: There are a lots of keyboard for android as Hacker's keyboard there is Go keyboard also bundled keyboard of android is capable to type it at least mine is.

Comment: @Arjan: Didn't see that. It's very odd to see what is effectively further reading about 2/3 way down the page. That section should definitely be moved to the end, possibly separated by a spacer in the contents list.

Comment: @avirk: Yes, my stock Android keyboard also can type a backtick. I was just suggesting that if the iOS stock keyboard was unable to type one (as apparently is the case for old versions), then there may be a better keyboard available to download.