# Please put the information about how to escape backticks in the main syntax help page

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, markdown, editing-help, backtick

I am fully aware that the information about how to escape backticks in inline code is on this page:

http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#autoescape

But since backticks are so commonly used on stackoverflow, I don't see why it should be so difficult to find. That page is very long already, but this one is pretty basic functionality, especially since backticks are so common in MySQL and C#.

- Escaping a backtick within inline code: `` This`is`not`straightforward ``
- But if you want to do adjacent backticks: ``` You have to use``three backticks ```
- How to do multiple backticks at the beginning of a line... You have to pick the number of backticks that's larger than your smallest number of backticks: ``` ``This is a triple double backtick`` ```
- Whitespace removal problems ``` (`` ` ``) ``` -> (`` ` ``)
- Displaying`backticks`in`plain`text`is`a`totally`different`escaping`system

I think this information should be added to the [advanced help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code), especially because a lot of the above is not on the Daring Fireball page.

I believe that this is not a duplicate of [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144105/please-include-how-to-quote-backticks-in-inline-code-in-markdown-editing-help) or any of the other threads on this subject for several reasons, including:

1. I'm asking for a feature request, as most of the other questions on this subject are asking "how do I do this" not "please add it to the help" like I am.
2. More in-depth discussion on why the Daring Fireball page is insufficient
3. Mention of MySQL and C# as specific places where backticking can be a problem

Comment: Also, in Haskell, backticks are used to apply a function infix: ``17 `div` 7`` instead of `div 17 7`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as the in-editor (or drop-down) help goes, this is getting a definite "no". That version of the help is supposed to be short and for the most common things.

I don't know about MySQL, but claiming "backticks are so common in C#" is a bit of a stretch, since they really only appear when you do reflection on generic types that are overloaded by their arity.

Secondly, in code *blocks* (where you'll find most of the code) this is of course not even an issue.

Thirdly, Gruber's Markdown page does indeed [mention this](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#code):

> To include a literal backtick character within a code span, you can use
>   multiple backticks as the opening and closing delimiters:
>
> ```
> ``There is a literal backtick (`) here.``
> ```
>
> which will produce this:
>
> ```
> <p><code>There is a literal backtick (`) here.</code></p>
> ```

(he also goes on to discuss the spaces-at-beginning-and-end thing).

I agree with you on adding the above to https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code, but *only* that part – any more than that can only make the text longer and more confusing without any gain.

So that part will be [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) after the next build; the rest is [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

Oh, and here's a little – undocumented, as far as I know :) – tip: You say

> You have to pick the number of backticks that's larger than your smallest number of backticks:

You don't actually have to. It just has to be a number that's *different* from the length of any sequence of backticks you use in the code, i.e. this:

```
` ``This is a triple double backtick`` `
```

gives the same result as your example.

Comment: Great answer! I don't want to change the drop down help, only the [FAQ page that you linked in your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). I'm going to edit my post... if you give me the tag [meta-tag:status-planned] I'll check mark your answer.

Comment: Nope, the change is already checked in, so this is completed, not planned :) This is what the corresponding section looks like after the next build: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LdHia.png

Comment: Haha, that works, ok, I just wanted any moderator tag really :)