# How do I drop code in? I know it's Apple K, or adding spaces but nothing is working even when I do that. New here

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I tried a couple different ways `enter code here`. I tried putting it in between the apostrophe's. I tried putting it in front of the 
    `enter code here`

Comment: Guess you are using iPhone? If not, what browser you have?

Comment: In case of iPhone: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133673/is-there-a-way-to-enter-back-tick-backtick-on-so-when-using-ipad-or-iphone

Answer (score 1):

If you want code inline like `this text`, you can enclose the text in back ticks '`', not apostrophes.

If you want to have a code block, you add four spaces before the text like:

```
this is a code block
on several lines
to be sure you can add an empty line before and after the codee block because 
some elements conflict with the code block
causeing the markup to fail.
```

In addition, you can also use the `<code>` tag. Both for `Inline code` and for:

`A code block enclosed in  tags.`