# Shortcut for code formatting in comments on mobile

Tags: feature-request, comments, ios-app, code-formatting, mobile-app

It's commonly known that you can use code formatting by surrounding your code with backticks: `` `enter code here` ``.

Unfortunately, the `` ` `` character is [fairly well hidden on the default iOS keyboard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133674/351462), making it inconvenient at best, or impossible to find at worst.

This isn't an issue when writing questions or answers, since there's a convenient "insert code button", but unfortunately there's no such button when writing comments.

There should be an alternative way of enclosing code on mobile devices, such as a code formatting button when writing comments.

Comment: Wait, it exists at all? TIL. I've tried to type backticks on mobile so many times only to give up and copy paste it.

Comment: Long pressing the apostrophe isn't really that inconvenient. I mean... apostrophes are a pretty commonly used thing and it's only very marginally more inconvenient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there ***is*** an alternative way to add code formatting to comments in the iOS app.

1. Highlight the text you want to format.
2. Click the 'more' arrow.

[image: more arrow]

3. Click Format.

[image: Format]

4. Click Code.

[image: Code]